Create SecKey from base64encoded string, PKCS8 format
I am trying to create a RSA private key, for decryption, from a base64 encoded string I get from a server. The private key is in PKCS8 format.
I created a sample private key using openssl:
openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -pubout -out publickey.crt
writing RSA key
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in keypair.pem -out pkcs8.key

Key:
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

Using a Java ASN.1 Decoder I am seeing the following structure:
PrivateKeyInfo SEQUENCE (3 elem)
version Version INTEGER 0
privateKeyAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier SEQUENCE (2 elem)
algorithm OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 rsaEncryption (PKCS #1)
parameters ANY NULL
privateKey PrivateKey OCTET STRING (1193 byte) 308204A50201000282010100BBAF75F4E4368E556D7426F64B1F558C5EED515B4C8F…
SEQUENCE (9 elem)
INTEGER 0
INTEGER (2048 bit) 236930859581060710757843464880341956857486468169895909962362617007724…
INTEGER 65537
INTEGER (2044 bit) 133934968343521166391522434123540422153557989067614000096596259419773…
INTEGER (1024 bit) 170301402303704933075773766952414999393762318598104529563061752888375…
INTEGER (1024 bit) 139124432550786015248088669876518155991728652141090969155587357230245…
INTEGER (1024 bit) 169207411270092473292370487035925585555094483083360156049686880709819…
INTEGER (1024 bit) 133938339371031521828324557687856272550500138520072533193503344936220…
INTEGER (1024 bit) 141321730700088593471292401527909895755863487096182952689250978863770…

I need to create a SecKey from the above structure.
Attempted:
I tried to do the following:
if let base = Data(base64Encoded: self.base64key) {
            guard 
                let privateKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(base as NSData, [
                kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
            ] as NSDictionary, nil) else {
                print("Could not create key")
                
                return
            }
            print(privateKey)
        }

Reference
I am thinking it does not strip the fields and make a key from the underlying keying material.
There is also swift-asn1 package that I am going through now. Seems like a lot of information to digest.
Does anyone have experience in pulling out the keying material and creating a key with it?

Status: Solved
I created an issue @ swift-asn1 and was able to get some help.
I ended up using swift-certificates to parse PrivateKeyInfo in ASN.1
To create a SecKey from a base64 encoded string holding a private key in PKCS8 format, I used this code in my project:
import Foundation
import X509
import _CryptoExtras
...
if let base = Data(base64Encoded: self.base64key) {
            do {
                let buffer = Array(base)
                /// Create private key structure.
                let key = try Certificate.PrivateKey(_RSA.Signing.PrivateKey(derRepresentation: buffer))
                /// Convert into PEM format.
                let pem = try key.serializeAsPEM()
                /// Drop header and footer.
                let string = pem.pemString.components(separatedBy: "\n").dropFirst().dropLast().joined()
                
                print(string)
                
                guard
                    let data = Data(base64Encoded: string),
                    let privateKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as NSData, [
                    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                    kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
                ] as NSDictionary, nil) else {
                    print("Could not create key")

                    return
                }
                print(privateKey)
                
            } catch {
                NSLog("Could not parse the buffer.")
            }
        }

Result:
<SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPrivateKey, version: 4, 2048 bits (block size: 256), addr: 0x600000d05b70>

